# Append multiple elements and use classes in JQuery append method

Tags: jquery, html

I use the jquery method append to create new divs under each other by clicking a button.

But it allows me to append only one div, so it does not look like i wanted it in this example (with a close symbol) to hide the div by clicking. Is this possible?

It would mean to append another span tag:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_alert

```js
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"
 
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#btn1").click(function () {
        $("#alerts").append(" <div>New Message from Whatsapp!</div>");
      });
    });
```

```css
  #alerts>div {
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background: #ECECEC;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    opacity: 0.7;
    border-radius: 15px;

  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1" >Whatsapp</button>
    <div id="alerts" ></div>
```

This is the error i get when i try to put the span tag inside the div, it seems to be a syntax error:

```js
        $("#alerts").append(" <div> <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>New Message from Whatsapp!</div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  The code explicitly appends one `<div>` element, and every time I click the button it successfully does exactly that.  Can you describe the problem?

Comment: The div does not have close tag (x) to close the div. That´s what i need. Like in the w3schools example

Comment: Well, the example to which you link includes `<span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>` in its HTML.  Did you try adding that to the `<div>` element you're appending?

Comment: yes i tried, it gives an error because it seems not to accept "onclick" and classes of the span tag i want to include

Comment: What did you try?  (Note that the code shown in the question does not include any such attempt.)  What was the error?  (Note that the code shown in the question does not produce this error.)  What do you mean by "it seems not to accept..."?  There's no reason you can't add attributes to your HTML elements.

Comment: I edited the answer to show the error and what i tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has syntax errors because you have a variety of quotes within a quoted string.  Since the string contains both single-quotes and double-quotes, you can't just pick one or the other.  So instead, pick one of them to "escape".  For example, here the string is still enclosed in double-quotes and then internally escapes its double-quote characters:

```js
$("#alerts").append("<div><span class=\"closebtn\" onclick=\"this.parentElement.style.display='none';\">&times;</span>New Message from Whatsapp!</div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="alerts"></div>
```

---

As an alternative, you can use a more structured syntax to build your elements with jQuery.  Something like this:

```js
let span = $('<span/>', { class: 'closebtn' }).html('&times;');
$('#alerts').append($('<div/>')
    .text('New Message from Whatsapp!')
    .prepend(span));
$(span).on('click', function () {
    this.parentElement.style.display='none';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="alerts"></div>
```

It appears much more verbose, so I suppose it's a matter of personal preference which approach you use.  But the benefit of this latter approach is that you break apart everything into individual operations, each doing its one thing in a simple and supportable manner, without in-line JavaScript in your markup or quoting issues or any of that.